# NDSolve not returning anything

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

Can anyone have a look over this .nb, as I am quite sure my set of 10 equations for 7 unknowns and 3 differentiated unknowns is valid? NDSolve returns nothing, it won't even give me an error message.

[Link to notebook](http://danielmaly.net/nondsolve.nb)

Comment: One issue is that you misspelled `NDSolve`. Next one is that I think you need to feed only differential equations to it.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I suspected it was something stupid... Thanks.

Comment: To correct my previous comment, from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html?q=NDSolve&lang=en) :
    NDSolve can solve many differential-algebraic equations, in which some of the eqns are purely algebraic, or some of the variables are implicitly algebraic.